# My friend can't join my ARK Survival Evolved Non-dedicated session

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

My friend and I are trying to play ARK Survival Evolved together and I have a bunch of progress on my single player world and I don't want to run a dedicated server because my PC can't handle it. But the problem is that he is on steam and Im on epic. I did some research and it said to run the command
-crossplay while hosting the session, but he can't even see my session at all. He searched for the name of my session but it just didn't pop up. I've even tried to join a non-dedicated session and then immediately leaving and going back to hosting the session. But even then he said it wouldn't pop up on his session list. He isn't subscribed to any mods at all so that's not an issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, Ark on Epic have some issues when creating no-dedicated sessions and the only way that i found to solve it is with HAMACHI following this steps:

1.- both of you download hamachi and create a room to be on the same net

2.- on Ark, one of you must create a non dedicated session and activate with console (press tab) the crossplay command

3.- the player that wants to join you need to start a local single player game and put on the console **open your_ip:7777** (your ip is the one that comes on hamachi) and wait to load your world

I play whith 3 of my friends on my non-dedicated server following this whithout problems

Note 1: when creating your non-dedicated server be sure to modify the "distance from host"  option to 99999999 so other players can roam the map freely

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I've done some more research and found out that it has to be a dedicated session.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and now with Hamachi, they can join me. Hamachi is a kind of VPN that can make you in direct connection with your friends.

Comment: Except Hamachi is really sketchy. Ive checked it out already. I even have a friend who also agrees with me